# Как перекинуть цифры на правую сторону ))) чтобы они встали ровно как на макете

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```css
.section__sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section__static {
  color: #242121;
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  /* 75% */
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  flex-flow: wrap-reverse;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="section__sidebar">
  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <h4 class="section__static">85%</h4>
    <img src="image/Vector.svg" alt="">
    <h5 class="section__desc">Приехали второй раз</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <h4 class="section__static">95%</h4>
    <img src="image/Vector-1.svg" alt="">
    <h5 class="section__desc">Научились кататься</h5>
  </div>


  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <h4 class="section__static">99%</h4>
    <img src="image/Vector-2.svg" alt="">
    <h5 class="section__desc">Довольных клиентов</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На картинке у тебя циферки явно не слева... ;)

Comment: уже исправил))))

Comment: Так ты и теги поменяй местами... `h4` и `img`.

Comment: Нечего не поменялось, я то спрашивал как перекинуть их на правую сторону

Answer (score 1):

inline-flex вам в помощь, только текст под волной придется абсолютно спозиционировать.

```css
.section__sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section__static {
  color: #242121;
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  /* 75% */
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  order: 2;
  /* flex-flow: wrap-reverse;*/
  /* position: absolute;*/
  /* display: flex;*/
  /* justify-content: flex-end;*/
}

.section__sidebar-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.section__desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section__sidebar">
  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <h4 class="section__static">85%</h4>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/170x10/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Slider-patients-photo-1" alt="">
    <h5 class="section__desc">Приехали второй раз</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <h4 class="section__static">95%</h4>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x10/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Slider-patients-photo-1" alt="">
    <h5 class="section__desc">Научились кататься</h5>
  </div>


  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <h4 class="section__static">99%</h4>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x10/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Slider-patients-photo-1" alt="">
    <h5 class="section__desc">Довольных клиентов</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему два слеша в vscode горит красным цветом в сss

Comment: уберите комментарии вообще. Неправильные использовала, в css // нет, только в sass.

Answer (score 0):

> Как перекинуть цифры на правую сторону ))) чтобы они встали ровно как на макете

Предложу такой вариант...

```css
.section__sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section__static {
  color: #242121;
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section__sidebar">
  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <table>
      <td><img src="image/Vector.svg" alt=""></td>
      <td><h4 class="section__static">85%</h4></td>
    </table>
    <h5 class="section__desc">Приехали второй раз</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <table>
      <td><img src="image/Vector-1.svg" alt=""></td>
      <td><h4 class="section__static">95%</h4></td>
    </table>
    <h5 class="section__desc">Научились кататься</h5>
  </div>


  <div class="section__sidebar-item">
    <table>
      <td><img src="image/Vector-2.svg" alt=""></td>
      <td><h4 class="section__static">99%</h4></td>
    </table>
    <h5 class="section__desc">Довольных клиентов</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-direction` одновременно и `row`, и `column` может и выглядит инновационно, но всё же лучше оставить что-то одно ;)

Comment: @Deonis, это стили ТСа, я их не трогал...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0, 500) scale(0.1,-0.1)"
fill="turquoise" stroke="none">
<path d="M0 4627 c0 -21 6 -25 49 -30 26 -3 93 -25 147 -49 96 -41 102 -43
204 -43 103 1 107 2 205 45 96 43 104 45 195 45 91 0 99 -2 195 -45 98 -44
102 -45 205 -45 103 1 107 2 205 45 96 43 104 45 195 45 90 0 100 -3 190 -42
55 -24 121 -45 153 -49 56 -7 57 -6 57 18 0 23 -5 26 -55 31 -30 3 -89 21
-135 42 -152 69 -270 68 -422 -2 -80 -36 -87 -38 -188 -38 -101 0 -108 2 -188
38 -152 71 -270 71 -424 1 -70 -32 -96 -38 -168 -42 -89 -4 -112 1 -255 61
-33 13 -84 28 -112 31 -51 6 -53 6 -53 -17z"/>

<path d="M0 4068 c0 -24 5 -26 70 -36 42 -6 104 -26 157 -51 106 -48 156 -61
248 -61 91 0 141 13 248 61 168 75 291 75 455 0 111 -51 174 -64 281 -59 71 4
102 11 176 42 168 70 165 69 270 69 106 0 115 -2 262 -67 54 -25 103 -39 148
-43 l67 -6 -4 29 c-3 28 -6 29 -66 36 -40 4 -94 21 -150 47 -116 53 -151 61
-257 61 -105 0 -140 -8 -258 -61 -157 -70 -280 -70 -435 -1 -126 57 -165 65
-290 60 -99 -4 -114 -7 -197 -45 -127 -58 -155 -65 -250 -65 -95 0 -123 7
-249 64 -67 31 -106 42 -158 46 -67 5 -68 4 -68 -20z"/>
<path d="M0 3487 l0 -34 75 -6 c60 -4 94 -14 172 -50 123 -56 157 -66 263 -73
111 -8 196 11 336 73 l109 48 140 0 c132 0 144 -2 205 -29 154 -67 184 -77
259 -88 112 -17 227 0 334 48 156 69 189 76 322 72 113 -4 125 -6 205 -42 123
-55 179 -73 254 -81 l66 -7 0 31 c0 17 -3 31 -7 31 -66 2 -164 28 -257 69
-217 96 -364 93 -601 -13 -144 -63 -302 -68 -434 -12 -31 13 -84 36 -118 50
-137 58 -326 56 -468 -6 -134 -58 -167 -68 -239 -78 -99 -14 -200 1 -301 46
-109 49 -178 70 -252 78 l-63 7 0 -34z"/>
</g>
<text fill="black" font-size="40" x="210" y="50">85%</text>
<text fill="black" font-size="20" x="0" y="70">Приехали второй раз</text>
<text fill="black" font-size="40" x="250" y="120">95%</text>
<text fill="black" font-size="20" x="0" y="130">Научились кататься</text>
<text fill="black" font-size="40" x="285" y="180">99%</text>
<text fill="black" font-size="20" x="0" y="190">Довольных клиентов</text>
</svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Я бы заморочилась))